# SQLite Queries

Tags: sqlite

I want to select some records from a table depending on multiple limitations 
like i want to get records which lies in a range < OR >
how can i write such query in SQLite.....?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the SQL dialect understood by SQLite is fairly standard so you can write a query such as this made-up example:

```
SELECT name, age, type
FROM pets
WHERE age < 2 OR age > 12 AND name LIKE "Mr%" AND type IN ("cat", "dog")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query a range you can use the `between` operator:

```
select col from Table where col2 between ? and ? order by col3
```

As [teabot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118484/sqlite-queries/1118606#1118606) notes, SQLite uses a pretty standard version of SQL and all the usual clauses are valid.